# Jest coverage still flagging line after applying test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have the following function in a React component that I am testing.

```
renderLoginLink(caption) {
    return (
      <a href="#" id="lnkAuthenticateWithGoogle" onClick={() => this.props.actions.authenticateWithGoogle()}>
       {caption}
      </a>
    );
  }
```

When I run jest --coverage that function is getting flagged.  I have written the following test for that function which passes.

```
describe('Login', () => {
    it('calls renderLoginLink()', () => {
        const actions = {
            authenticateWithGoogle: jest.fn()
        }
        const expectedNode = <a href="#" id="lnkAuthenticateWithGoogle" onClick={() => actions}>testCaption</a>

        let node = document.createElement('div');
        let instance = ReactDOM.render(<Login {...initialState} />, node);
        expect(JSON.stringify(instance.renderLoginLink("testCaption"))).toEqual(JSON.stringify(expectedNode));
    });
});
```

I'm not sure what I am missing or what other test I could write that would satisfy jest coverage.

Comment: Does running `jest --clearCache` first fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `shallow` and `simulate` from enzyme:

```javascript
function setup() {
  const props = {
    actions: {
      authenticateWithGoogle: jest.fn(),
    },
  };

  return { props };
}

describe('Login', () => {
  const props = setup();
  const component = shallow(<Login {...props} />);

  it('calls renderLoginLink() ', () => {
    const loginLink = component.find('lnkAuthenticateWithGoogle');
    loginLink.simulate('click');
    expect(props.actions.authenticateWithGoogle).toBeCalled();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're telling jest that the onclick handler should equal this:

```
() => actions
```

which is a function that returns an object and does nothing else.

Instead, I would render the component with `shallow()`, pass in the `authenticateWithGoogle` function as a jest stub, and verify clicking on the `<a>` calls the mock.